# What is the benefit of using CDH (cloudera)?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, apache-spark, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

Why we use CDH (cloudera) instead of using Apache-Hadoop or Apache-Spark ets. solely? What is it's advantages?

If I want to use Apache-Spark for data analysis, is it better to use CDH or Apache-Spark Framework Solely?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, CDH is a "Hadoop distribution". For me, it is "a simple way of installing Hadoop" and having a nice web interface for administration. So you can't really use CDH *instead* of Hadoop. (Just as you can't use Red Hat instead of Linux.)

Spark can also run as a stand-alone cluster without Hadoop. However, then you won't be able to use HDFS resource locality information and YARN scheduling.

To get started with Spark, I would recommend to try the stand-alone cluster first, as Hadoop is quite a beast to get started with. However, if you need HDFS functionality from the start on, then I guess you'll have to set up Hadoop (in any form) anyway.

Comment: Thanks for answer. but for get started with Spark, why you recommend to try the stand-alone cluster first? Why I don't use CDH which has Spark itself?

Comment: Just noting that even on CDH, there are two flavors of Spark available, the stand-alone version (where the Spark daemon is just installed on every node) and the YARN version (where executors are started as a result of resource negotiation).

Otherwise, for myself, I just found installing CDH a very lengthy and partially frustrating process, so I wouldn't try to avoid this hurdle when getting started with an only partially related technology.

Comment: It depends on long term perspective. If You stay with spark - or will grow and use more the ecosystem.